# Compensating for aggressive stemming in solr

Tags: solr, stemming

I'm trying to accomplish two things in the backend when I'm building a solr text query: adding in false negatives and removing false positives.

In the context of stemming, compensating for a false negative would mean adding the string "children" to a query that is looking for the word "child", because the irregular plural's stem does not match the singular form's stem.

A false positive is harder to find an english example of, but a hypothetical example would be that the word "recreation" is stemmed to the same stem as "create". In this case, we still want use the stemmer so that "recreational" is given as a result, but we still want to block any instances of "create".

My initial attempt at a solution is to create two text fields, one with a stemmer and the other without the stemmer. The fields would otherwise share the same tokenizer, normalizer, and other properties. The reason why is because if I used the following query

```
text_en:(recreation -"create")
```

then if "recreation" and "create" are both stemmed to "creat" solr seems to interpret it as "return all documents that HAVE the "creat" stem, and do NOT HAVE the "creat" stem", which would obviously return no documents.

So I've tried using a field without a stemmer, combined with the stemmed field like so

```
(text_en:recreation AND
text_en_norm:(-"create"))
```

Where text_en_norm is the field that is unstemmed. The raw text of both fields is identical.  However, this doesn't seem to work as expected. Instances of the word "create" are still returned. Is there a problem with my query or have I misunderstood something more fundamental?

Comment: Have you tried using different stemming filters (there's a few that's dictionary based as well), or marked the false positives as keywords instead (where stemming doesn't occur). We've had a few cases where we've had to modify the underlying Snowball stemmer to get the results we want as well.

Comment: I haven't used different stemming filters, because the solution I'm looking for  has to be applied to languages that have only one stemmer option which work fairly poorly. I gave the english examples to convey the issue. What did you mean by marking false positives as keywords? I believe that's what I'm doing here.

Comment: @MatsLindh I just reread this question (and the @ commenting convention to notify you) and had to ask, when you say 'modifying the underlying snowball stemmer' do you mean modifying the solr source code or just changing stemmer called for in the config?

Comment: Well, not exactly the Solr source - but the snowball stemmer included in the Lucene source (so yes, you'll have to get the source, make modifications and recompile). You will get different results with other stemmers, so it's worth exploring as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with my query syntax. The following query works.

```
((text_en:"recreation" ) AND !text_en_norm:("create"))
```

However, this methodology introduces a bug. A document may contain both a false positive and correct result, but not get returned. e.g, "Universities create Recreational Centers for their students." This would not get returned due to the blocked results. It may seem rare but I've already seen it occur in my application.